# How do I compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dxdy$? Or why doesn't it converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm having a bit of trouble calculating the double integral using the following function: $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x\geq 0 \text{ and } x\leq y<x+1\\ -1, \text{ if } x\geq 0 \text{ and } x+1\leq y\leq x+2\\ 0,\text{ else} \end{cases}$$ My attempt in computing the integral left me to believe that I needed to write $x$ in terms of $y$. This would give me $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\geq 0\;\;,\; y-1<x\leq y\}$ as the first set on which $f(x,y)=1$ and $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\geq 0\;\;,\; y-2\leq x\leq y-1\}$ as the set on which $f(x,y)=-1$ (and $f(x,y)=0$ everywhere else). But how do I put this in terms of the integral? I think that it is needed to integrate from $y=0$, since $f(0,0)=1$, but that means that something like \begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_{y-1}^ydx-\int_{y-2}^{y-1}dx\right)\end{align*} wouldn't work, since we could be integrating over negative $y$. My "solution" to this was to simply plug in an indicator function (which I'll denote with $\chi(x)$), which is equal to 1 if $x\geq0$ and $0$ else. This would give us:
\begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_{y-1}^y\chi(x)dx-\int_{y-2}^{y-1}\chi(x)dx\right).\end{align*}
However, I do not know how to evaluate something like this. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've heard that the integral diverges, so I adjusted the question likewise. Can anyone help me or give me a hint why this is the case?

Comment: This integral doesn't converge. Is there a notion of regularization that would be "natural" given the context of wherever this problem came from?

Comment: Oh I actually didn't expect that. The exercise was to show that int_{-\infty}^{\infty}int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) dx dy \neq int_{-\infty}^{\infty}int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy dx. Since I computed that int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy =0 (I hope that that is right), I didn't really think about the possibility that the integral diverges. Do you perhaps know why it diverges? I will directly edit the question

Comment: The domain of the function is unbounded and the function doesn't decay. You can make this integral equal any real number you want.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll try to prove that (that it can be equal to any real number). Ty for the hint